# Shifting jQuery focus to next div separated input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 inputs for every `div` container (e.g. `first-section`, `second-section` ...), and I have several such `div` containers on my page, similar to this:

```
...
<div id="first-section">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>First Section</legend>
        <input type="number" placeholder="000" id="input1" min="0" max="255" autofocus maxlength="3" required>
...
    </fieldset>     
</div>
<div id="second-section">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Second Section</legend>
        <input type="number" placeholder="000" id="input2" autofocus min="0" max="255" maxlength="3" required>
...
```

how can I use jQuery to move from `input1` to `input2` to `input3` (not shown) to `input4` (not shown) only after the user has entered the maxlength of input which is set to 3? My jQuery below does not work because when I move onto the third input (not shown), it keeps resetting the focus back to input 2.

```
$(':input').keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr('maxlength')){
        $(this).nextAll(':input').first().focus();

        if($('#input1').val().length==$('#input1').attr('maxlength')){
            $('#input2').focus();
        }
    }


})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the `div` that contains the current input, then find the next sibling of the div and the input inside the next div element and set the focus to that.

```
$(this).closest('div').next().find(':input').first().focus();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4q27kj4r/)

Answer (score 2):

The above one has following issues:

- unable to move to previous tab once its filled.
- skips the text box which is already filled.
- makes things worst if you have JS validations on any input fields.

Use the below jQuery plug-in its easy to configure and use:

Developer Site: http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/

Documentation:  https://github.com/Mathachew/jquery-autotab/blob/master/README.md

**Includes both Angular and React examples**

Cheers...